# How can I create an HTML table layout with rows from a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

On my "popular tags" page, I am fetching all of the tags from the database with this PHP & SQL in order from most popular to least popular:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.tagid, t.name, t.desc, COUNT(qt.id) AS total
        FROM tags t
        LEFT JOIN question_tags qt ON t.tagid=qt.tag_id
        GROUP BY t.tagid, t.name
        ORDER BY total DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<div class="tag-list-box" id="tag-'.$row['tagid'].'">
        <a href="/tags/'.strtolower($row['name']).'" class="tag">
        <span class="label label-inverse label-tag">'.strtolower($row['name']).'</span>
        </a> <strong>&times; '.$row['total'].'</strong><br />
        <p>'.($row['desc']!==null ? $row['desc'] : '<em>This tag has no description.</em>').'</p>
        </div>';
}
```

I don't have it in an HTML table right now because I thought I could do it the *more "modern way"* with divs and CSS, but as you can see in this screenshot below, the rows get messed up when a tag has a description because the height of the box is greater than the others:

[image]

My CSS for the boxes is:

```
.tag-list-box {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I am thinking I should put it in a table which should fix the problem but my question is **how do I make every 4 rows from the query have their own `<tr>` so there can be 4 in each table row?**

I can't figure it out — I tried doing a count and incrementing it in the `while` loop but then I just don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Looks like somebody is trying to create a  mini-SO, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I would check to see if you have 4 in a row like Scott said, however. You can use divs. After every 4 just add a div that clears the left float. I would NOT use a set height because you never know how tall the items will get. Example of what I would do:

```
$count = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '...'; //YOUR CURRENT ECHO STATEMENT HERE
  $count++;
  if($count % 4 == 0) echo "<div style='clear: left;'></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the modulo operator to see if your count is divisible by 4:

```
if($count % 4 == 0)
```

If you want to keep your css solution, you can also set a height for your divs and then set overflow to hidden to handle descriptions that are too long.

Comment: If JS is an option, he could also add an equal height mechanism, it would be a nice addition (and to me, better than having text cut by the hidden overflow)

Comment: @DamienPirsy I could do that (and yes JS is an option), but I don't think the descriptions will be that long. Thanks for the idea though :)

Comment: I'm having a little problem (I'm probably just not doing it right), it is doing this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25819920/Screen%20shot%202012-06-15%20at%202.47.43%20PM.png Here's the code: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25819920/Screen%20shot%202012-06-15%20at%202.45.00%20PM.png